# Display Matched String By Click On Particular Alphbet

Tags: android, android-listview

```
public void displayListItem()
{
    double pixelPerIndexItem = (double) sideIndexHeight / indexListSize;
    int itemPosition = (int) (sideIndexY / pixelPerIndexItem);
    int minPosition = (int) (itemPosition * pixelPerIndexItem);
    Object[] indexItem = indexList.get(itemPosition);


    int indexMin = Integer.parseInt(indexItem[1].toString());
    int indexMax = Integer.parseInt(indexItem[2].toString());
    int indexDelta = Math.max(1, indexMax - indexMin);

    double pixelPerSubitem = pixelPerIndexItem / indexDelta;
    int subitemPosition = (int) (indexMin + (sideIndexY - minPosition) / pixelPerSubitem);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    listView.setSelection(subitemPosition);
}
```

in my code.it is displaying the list from the middle but not from the starting.

so how to do. it should display the code from where it starts

Answer (score 0):

change
listView.setSelection(subitemPosition)
to
listView.setSelectionFromTop(indexMin + itemPosition, 0);